# On the (non) uniqueness of the extension of unbounded operators and their generated semigroups

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A$ be a closed densely-defined linear operator. Suppose $A$ is unbounded (if not the questions are trivial).

Do there exist any proper closed extension $A'$ of $A$?

Is the set of closed extensions of $A$ a chain? (If $A_1$, $A_2$ are two extensions, can we affirm that $A_2$ is an extension of $A_1$ or vice versa?)

If so, let $A'$ be a closed proper extension and suppose $A$, $A'$ generate two $c_0$-semigroups $\Phi$, $\Phi'$.

What is the relationship of $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$?

Comment: Have you looked at any operator theory textbooks? This is pretty standard material. You can find an example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators#An_example

Comment: The examples furnished by differentiation on the interval with various domains also show how different the semigroups can be. In principal the semigroup of differentiation is the translation flow but, in the case of Dirichlet boundary conditions, the functions "fall off the edge of the interval" when translated. When, however, periodic boundary conditions are imposed (maybe with a cocycle) the translation flow becomes unitary.

Comment: I'm following Evan's book "Partial Differential Equations", the only ones a took a look about operator theory were about C*-algebras and bounded operators. Is there any good book about unbounded operators? (I'm interesting also in the possible relationship of the abstract C*-algebra and the Von Neumann algebra, C*-algebra with predual, with unbounded operators, which seems to be defined in a concrete Hilbert space).

Comment: I don't understand very much the example. $f$ is absolutely continuous if $f\in H^1(0,1)$? Is $A=i\frac{d}{dx}$ self-adjoint in $L^2(0,1)$ with domain $D(A)=H^1_0(0,1)$? Is the same differentiation operator self-adjoint with domains $D(A_2)=\{f \in H^1(0,1) \; | \; f(0)=0 \}$, $D(A_3)=\{f \in H^1(0,1) \; | \; f(0)=f(1) \}$, $D(A_4)=\{f \in H^1(0,1) \; | \; f(0)=\lambda f(1), \; \lambda\in U(1)\}$, $D(A_5)=H^1(0,1)$, or only closed and symmetric? Are all the semigroups "almost" translation flow but some cases "fall off" because of the boundary condition?

Comment: The example is explained on page 257 on Reed and Simon's Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics (I'm looking at 2nd edition published by Academic Press, 1980)